# you gonna cut us a deal seeing as how it used to be yours?

Tags: meaning

Here is the sentence I don't understand. 
This is the dialogue between A and B.

Now A has food truck which was B's truck. B is working at Speedy Lube for living. 
Speedy Lube looks like a fictitious Car Maintenance & Servicing.

A came to B to ask something and then he said this sentence before leave.

> A: Hey, if I bring your truck back here to Speedy Lube, **you gonna cut me a deal seeing as how it used to be yours? You know, before you hit rock bottom.**

I really don't get it the bold part. Could you help me?

Comment: **'To hit rock bottom'**  means to reach at the lowest point of one's life, for that individual could not be more low-spirited than he is now. It's a commonly used idiom

Comment: To cut a deal means to give a discount.  is that what you don't get?

Comment: Perhaps what you're missing is the implied word _**are**_ before the word _you_ which is left off because it is superfluous? That would make the bold text _**...[are] you gonna [give me a discount] seeing as how it used to be yours? You know, before you [reached the lowest point in your life, likely forcing you to sell me this truck just to make ends meet]**_.

Answer (score 2):

To *cut someone a deal* means to give a discount.

*Seeing as how* is an idiom that has a meaning similar to *because*.  In this case it is used to introduce the reason he thinks he should have a discount, which is that the person doing the job used to own the vehicle.

*To hit rock bottom* is a reference to being at the lowest point in your life.  If you dig down through the dirt, eventually you hit rock and can't go any lower.  He's just saying this because Shawn Spencer has no sense of social etiquette.

Comment: _Rock bottom_ could also refer to the lowest price someone is going to offer for something. For example: _The housing market in Detroit has seen rock bottom prices in real estate_. (That's not the intended meaning here, but I believe it's worth mentioning in a footnote.)

Comment: @J.R., I don't think "the lowest price someone is going to offer" is an accurate alternate meaning: even in the example you used, the meaning is more "reached the lowest possible price", and has a negative connotation.  You might say "he offered me a rock bottom price for the car", but it still has the connotation of having sunk to the lowest level.

Comment: @AlannaRose - What's bad for the seller can be good for the buyer. I've often seen "rock bottom prices" used as a sales pitch, be it for [books](https://www.washingtonpost.com/lifestyle/travel/six-times-a-year-book-lovers-flock-to-shenandoah-valley-for-rock-bottom-prices/2016/08/04/a54d52fe-5416-11e6-88eb-7dda4e2f2aec_story.html), [clothes](http://mumssavvysavings.com/get-bargain-designer-clothes-at-rock-bottom-prices/), [car parts](http://www.rockbottomgmparts.com/), or [airline tickets](http://www.abcactionnews.com/news/frontier-airlines-offering-rock-bottom-prices-on-select-cities-dates).

Answer (score -2):

The guy is asking for a cut price because the truck being lubed used to belong to the luber. He is also insulting him by reminding him that he had hit rock bottom at the time. A deal will not be cut.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We hope you'll answer more questions, and welcome to ELL. To be useful, since our readers are learning English, idioms such as _rock bottom_ need to be explained, as well as _sentence structure_ and _parts of speech._

Comment: The OP indicates they don't know what "rock bottom" means, and the crux of your answer is summarized in"rock bottom". Hence, this doesn't answer the question at hand.